# How to use special variables in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use dp/L and dp/L-fit variable of dictionary in html table rows in django template.

Example:
`[{'PIR': 3133510.2695076177, 'PVR': 13810.315856115429, 'curve': [{'v': 0.1633026324384349, 'dP/L': 85905.56295072743, 'dP/L-fit': 85818.9286758735, 'error': -0.001008482709130518}]}]`

When I use `{{ dP/L }}`, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you just can't use special characters in template variable.
So if you want to do use a special characters key in template create a custom templatetags:
create template tag file for app like templatetags/dict_tags.py

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_value(d, key):
   return d.get(key)
```

and in template

```html
{% load dict_tags %}

{{ dict_variable | get_value:'dP/L' }}
```